# Why is there an "undefined reference to" error for my copy constructor?

Tags: c++, initializer-list, constructor-overloading

I thought I had set everything up correctly for my `initializer-list constructor`, but apparently, there is still something off about it. It is supposed to be an `overloaded constructor` for my `Matrix class` that creates a `Matrix` from this type of input: `Matrix d = {{1,3}, {5,9};` I know one of my definitions is incorrect, but I can't decipher which one(s).

```
Matrix::Matrix(const i_list & list){
  uint rows = list.size();
  uint cols = list.begin()->size();
  int i = 0;
  mat = new double*[rows];
  for(uint m = 0; m < rows; m++){
    mat[m] = new double[rows];
  }
  for(uint n = 0; n < rows; k++){
    for(uint w = 0; w < cols; w++){
      mat[n][w] = *(list.begin()[n].begin[w] + i);
      i++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You probably want the `Matrix(const Matrix& param)` signature. Here is the copy constructor [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor).

Comment: `mat[m] = new double[rows];` shouldn't that be `cols`?

Comment: Is `i_list` is an alias for `std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<double>>`?

Comment: Yes it is an alias for that declared in my header file.

Answer (score 2):

The line `mat[n][w] = *(list.begin()[n].begin[w] + i);` is basically nonsense. You can loop over the input, which means you don't need a separate loop.

```
Matrix::Matrix(const i_list & list){
  mat = new double*[list.size()];
  for(auto r = list.begin(); r != list.end(); ++r){
    auto row = mat[r - list.begin()] = new double[r->size()];
    for(auto c = r->begin(); c != r->end(); ++c){
      row[c - r->begin()] = *c;
    }
  }
}
```

But what you *should do* is change `mat` from a `**double` to a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`, at which point it becomes:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const i_list & list) : mat(list) {}
```

Comment: That seems like a better, cleaner approach. I tried the nested for-loops because I wanted fill rows and columns with it, but I think I'll go about trying it in this way now.